# Why i'm Getting Call to a member function formName() on null in yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, active-form

I can't find any supporting resources for the error **Call to a member function formName() on null**. The scenario of getting this error when opening a update page. I've checked the rendered variable on update page by print_r() and its fine.
Then I checked by **removing** the all input field which codes in yii2 ActiveFrom chtml

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'class' => ' form-control']) ?>
```

and kept some input fields which is in normal html syntax

```
<input type="text" class="qty" name="qty[]" value="1" style="width: 24px;" value="<?php echo $value->qty; ?>">
```

Then it worked.
Why this error occurred and how to fix it.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not passing an update model from controller's action to view. Make sure you pass the loaded model in your update action to view like this:

```php
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    //... other update action code

    return $this->render('update', ['model' => $model]);
}
```

If you are using some common `_form` template that you include into your create/update templates you also have to make sure the `$model` is passed from your `update` template to the `_form` template.

```html
<!-- ... your update template code ... -->
<?= $this->render('_form', ['model' => $model]); ?>
<!-- ... the rest of update template ... -->
```

Another option is that you are overwiriting the $model variable somewhere in your templates.